# Cakephp routing issue for passing parameters from URL

Tags: cakephp, routes, controller

For cakePHP routing, I understand that if you do

```
Router::connect(
    '/:controller/:id',
    array('action' => 'view'),
    array('id' => '[0-9]+')
);
```

That would map to any urls that are http://www.mywebsite.com/controller/view/id,

but how about mapping urls that are http://www.mywebsite.com/controller/id/action?

For ex: http://www.mywebsite.com/classes/3/create/2

and in my create function in Classes controller,

it will receive parameter $id, which is 3 in this case, and $count, which is 2 in this case,

```
public function create( $id, $count ) {
    ....
    // i can here create a total number of $count students
    // and assign them class_id $id

    // so  student1.class_id = 3
    // and student2.class_id = 3
}
```

And I tried,

```
Router::connect(
'/:controller/:id/:action',
    array('id' => '[0-9]+'),
    array('count' => '[0-9]{,2}')
);
```

It didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In order for Cake to pass id and count to your controller action, you have to make the route know they are passed arguments. To do so, include them in the `pass` array in the last option in the order you want them to be passed.

You were also missing `:count` in your route, so it wouldn't be matched if you passed a count.

Your new route should look like this:

```
Router::connect(
    '/:controller/:id/:action/:count',
    array(),
    array(
  'pass' => array('id', 'count'),
  'id' => '[0-9]+',
      'count' => '[0-9]{,2}'
)
);
```

Comment: My get value is like this    /android-atc-training-certification-courses.   Just after main url. then how can I achieve this...?